# Mail composer to front

Tags: iphone, xcode, sendmail, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller with UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl.
On that view i have a "send email" button.
When i click on it the mail composer sheet is showing but its going under the PartialCurl.
Is there any way to display it in front?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: SH]

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:mailcomposerview];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it says: Incompatible pointer types sending 'MFMailComposeViewController*_strong to parameter of type 'UIView*'

Comment: Do you think that Apple can reject my app for such thing? cau's if not, i don't mind that it would stay in that way.. :)